# Find duplicate lines in a text file (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, file

I have a .txt filled with data that I want to filter, since some lines occur as duplicates with the only difference that the timestamp is exactly 2 hours later. Those lines that are the late version of the duplicate (so for example the first line in the attached example) should be left out. All other lines should be left in and written to a new .txt file.

```
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 16:11:56 00:00:40    2   Sensor Check   #   should go
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 14:12:40 00:00:33    2   Sensor Check   #   should go
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 14:11:56 00:00:40    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 16:12:40 00:00:33    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 17:23:25 00:00:20    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:23:25 00:00:20    2   Sensor Check   #   should go
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:15:24 00:02:21    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:25:13 00:02:13    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
```

I tried to write some Python code to perform the task, but I'm afraid coding has been a little too long ago for me to succeed. Can anyone provide me with some feedback on the issue? See my code below.

```
def filter_file():
    with open("output.txt", "w") as output: 
        with open("input.txt","r") as logger_input:
            for line in logger_data:
                if...:
                #compare current line with all other lines and DON'T copy
                #current line to output file if:                
                     #1. Machine number is similar (eg 1_3_IMM) &
                     #2. Date stamp is similar &
                     #3. Time stamp is similar with a +02:00:00 difference
                else:                                           
                   output.write(...)   #write line to output file
                   output.write("\n")  #go to new line

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filter_file()
```

Thanks!

Comment: How many lines are in the file?

Comment: That depends, but right now I have a file of 5823 lines